# How to extract current revision from SVN (subversion) repo directory+files

Tags: subversion

I have an SVN repo that is managed via web interface (`svn checkout https://server/repos/proj1` etc.), which all works.

Now, with every `commit` I wish to copy the newest version in a directory, e.g. into `/home/user/somewhere/proj1/rev102/` using a shell command on the server.

If I remember correctly you can call a command upon every `commit` and I am not worried much about how it is done (that failing I could create a `cron` job), but:

How do I extract the newest files from the svn repo directory/files using a locally running shell script without using `svn update`, svn login mechanisms etc.?  All the files are there and accessible from the shell, so that ought to be easy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need an `svn login` if you have direct file access to the svn database. 
Somewhere on the server you have the root of the svn database, say directory `/some/dir`. It has subdirectories `db`, `conf`, `hooks` and `locks`.  You can checkout this
repository on the same machine by using

```
cd /home/user/somewhere/
svn list file:///some/dir/
svn checkout file:///some/dir/repos/proj1/rev102  proj1/rev102
```

You can also do `svn update` in the newly created subdirectory.

As you say, you can call a command on every commit. Edit and rename the file
`hooks/post-commit.tmpl` to `hooks/post-commit` in `/some/dir`.